# Why do I get an error when using std::find() on a vector?

Tags: c++, vector

I'm trying to use the `std::find()` function on a `std::vector`. Why does this code bring up an error, and how can I fix this?

```
struct person_id{
    int p_id;
};
std::vector<person_id> people;

person_id tmp_person;
tmp_person.p_id = 5;
people.push_back(tmp_person);

if(std::find(people.begin(), people.end(), 5) != people.end()) {
    cout<<"Contain"<<endl;
} else {
    cout<<"Not Contain"<<endl;           
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `constructor` and `operator ==` to fix the compiler error

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
struct person_id{
    person_id() = default;
    person_id(int id) : p_id (id) {}

    bool operator==(const person_id& other) { return p_id == other.p_id; }
    int p_id;
};
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    std::vector<person_id> people;

    person_id tmp_person;
    tmp_person.p_id = 5;
    people.push_back(tmp_person);

    if(std::find(people.begin(), people.end(), 5) != people.end()) {
        cout<<"Contain"<<endl;
    } else {
        cout<<"Not Contain"<<endl;           
    }
    return 0;
}
```

- constructor is used to implicitly convert 5(int type) into `struct person_id`
- operator== is required by the `std::find` function

Check it here:
https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/437f4ec26bbc7995

Comment: Thank you. Can you explain  bool operator==(const person_id& other) { return p_id == other.p_id; } this part more specifically plz?

Comment: `operator ==` is used to compare the objects, you may reference the answer here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading

Comment: And the document here:https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators

Comment: Or the similar method, define a global compare == operator like this: `bool operator ==(const person_id &a, const person_id &b);`

Answer (score 2):

Your vector is the container of type `person_id`, you search using an `int` value. How should compiler know that the integer literal `5` shall be compared with the `p_id` field?

The simple solution is to have a `vector<int>`: why do you need that struct? If you still need that type, define the comparison operator or conversion operator... There are many ways to implement this, give us more details.

Comment: I am new to c++ so confusing.... do you mean I should change struct to int?? What are the ways that if I want to keep in struct?

Comment: The easiest thing to do is probably searching for `person_id{5}` instead of `5`

Comment: The "proper" way to do this would be to explicitly compare `p_id` with `5` using `find_if`

Comment: You should understand the task. If you plan to bring more sense to the entity `Person`, you may add more operations. You should hide the `p_id` field using the `private` access modifier to prevent unintentional access, and expose the `public` operations, etc. Overall that is the question of the task, not of the language.

Comment: @Kerndog73 The `person_id::p_id` already looks like a tautology, so there is no proper way.